# Puzzling Bash behaviour

Tags: bash

I just want to declare a few variable names on a single line. These names should be visible as names which have been *taken*, even if not necessarily set to a specific value.

In `C`, I would do this:

```
int i, j, k;
```

In `Bash`, I am welcomed to a world of astonishment:

```
declare -a a1 a2 a3; echo ${!a*}
```

outputs:

```
a1 a2 a3
```

Works! :) But these are arrays so presumably they are created empty.. not the right example.

Let's try again. This:

```
declare -r b1 b2 b3; echo ${!b*}
```

outputs:

```
<nothing>
```

but now:

```
b1=foo
```

bombs with:

```
bash: b1: readonly variable
```

Odd.

It marks the name as read-only but the name itself is not seen by `${!...}` indirection.

Makes me wanna tell `Bash` "make up your mind! do you know of these symbols or not?"

Anyway, surely this will work:

```
declare -g c1 c2 c3; echo ${!c*}
```

outputs:

```
<nothing>
```

Finally:

```
declare -x d1 d2 d3; echo ${!d}
```

outputs:

```
<nothing>
```

What is puzzling is that:

```
declare -p
```

*sees* all defined variables but they are only printed by `${!...}` calls if they have been assigned a value. But the `man` page does not say: "those names which have a value will be expanded..". Strange.

So I concluded that this would not work to declare my variable names, as I originally intended and is my objective anyway, because I am not assigning a value:

```
declare y1= y2= y3=; echo ${!y*}
```

... but, to my dismay, this yields:

```
y1 y2 y3
```

So the question becomes:

**Which values have y1, y2, y3 after `declare y1= y2= y3=`?**

I have tried to answer myself, because if the are finally seen as available names, these variables **must** have something in them. Even, possibly, the `\0` value. Should they not, none of the above would make sense, right?

```
printf "$v1" > /tmp/tmp
```

gives this:

```
hexdump -C /tmp/tmp
<nothing>
```

and:

```
wc -c /tmp/tmp
```

gives:

```
0 /tmp/tmp
```

File completely empty.

Anybody understands this? All I wanted to do, was a `C`-like `int i, j, k;`..

I need it because in my functions I very reasonably check some user and environment conditions by checking whether some variables are "visible". Based on that, the script does something and updates these status-signalling variables. It is inconsistent that something that should go into the symbol table, and appear in declare -p independently of having a value or not, would appear in variable name expansion *only* if it has a value.. with the exception of setting a  value, completely empty, which makes the name visible again. Clearly I cannot rely on a consistent behaviour here?

Comment: I don't have time to answer this well right now. Bash has a (undocumented) concept of "hidden variables". Whether a variable is set when measured in various ways depends upon several factors and differs between shells. Basically in Bash (and according to POSIX), a variable is "set" only when it has been given a value. There are even differences between `readonly` (POSIX) and `declare -r` (bashism). I wouldn't worry about fully understanding this unless you want to dive really deep... See [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/083) for the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question becomes:
>
> **Which values have y1, y2, y3 after `declare y1= y2= y3=`?**

The answer to your question lies in `declare -p`:

```
cobalt@carbon:~ $ declare foo
cobalt@carbon:~ $ declare -p | grep -- "-- foo"
declare -- foo
cobalt@carbon:~ $ declare foo=
cobalt@carbon:~ $ declare -p | grep -- "-- foo"
declare -- foo=""
cobalt@carbon:~ $ declare -a foo
cobalt@carbon:~ $ declare -p | grep foo
declare -a foo='([0]="")'
```

`${!prefix*}` apparently expands only names of variables that have been declared with a value assigned to them. A simple declaration does not assign a value, regardless of whether the variable is exported (`-x`) or declared global (`-g`). Declaration of array variables (`declare -a var`), however, is different, because it does assign a value. The same goes for declaration with explicit assignment of a value (`declare var=`).